# Find all directories, in which user has access to search and echo this directories in shell

Tags: linux, shell, find, ksh, chmod

I need to find all directories, in which user has access to search(command `find`) and echo this directories in shell. USER is read from ksh.

for example:

```
read user
```

I know, if user want to use `find` in directory, user should have "read access" and "execute access" for this directory. I should check all directories for `r` and `x` access for inputed user.

Answer (score 3):

I wont give you the exact code but can give you the steps to achieve this:

- Find the owner of the directory. If this matches with the `user` for which   you are searching, then check the owner permissions on that directory. If it is `r+x(5)` or `r+w+x(7)`, then the user can search inside that directory, otherwise not.
- If  the owner of the directory doesn't match with the user, check the group of the directory and find out whether the entered `user` belongs to that group or not. If the user belong. Check the group permissions on that directory. If it is `r+x(5)` or `r+w+x(7)`, then the user can search inside that directory, otherwise not.
- If the entered `user` doesn't belong to the group of the directory, check the others permissions on that directory. If it is `r+x(5)` or `r+w+x(7)`, then the user can search inside that directory, otherwise not.

I think the above algo will perform the task which you want.

**Edit:**

Method 1:

You can use find command for that:

```
$ find / -maxdepth 1 -type d -perm -u=rx
```

This will find all directories inside / upto one level with user permission as **atleast** (read+execute).

Method 2:

```
$ stat <filename/directoryname>  | grep Access | head -1 | awk 'BEGIN{FS="[/)]"} {print $2}'
```

This will give you the permissions in rwx notation (eg. drwxr-xr-x)

```
$ stat <filename/directoryname>  | grep Access | head -1 | awk 'BEGIN{FS="[(/]"} {print $2}'
```

This will give you the permissions in 755 notation (eg. 0755)

Comment: how to check permission of directory?

Comment: stat will give you file/directory permissions.

In general, your script cannot find all the directories you want.  As an example, if you have perms 711 on /a and perms 755 on /a/b (and you're not the owner), you cannot search /a but you can search /a/b.

Comment: @AlexZern: I have updated the answer for your question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if I understand your question in its current form.

If you don't care about a sub-directory with read access being placed in a directory without read access, then you can simply do:

```
find . -type d -perm -u+r
```

If you want to know, whether a specific user has read access to a directory, then get the group(s) she/he is a member of:

```
groups $userID
```

And do:

```
find . -type d -group $groupID -perm -g+r
```